# How to refer cloudformation resources in a nested stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

I've a template.yaml (in root folder), and ecs_job_definitions.yaml and a ecs_job_definitions.yaml files inside "nested-stack-templates" folder

In the template.yaml file I want to refer to my ecs_job_definitions.yaml

```
Resources:

  ECSJobDefinitionsStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: 'nested-stack-templates/ecs_job_definitions.yaml'
      Parameters:
        SesToAddress: !Ref SesToAddress
        DockerImageURIForDashboard: !Ref DockerImageURIForDashboard
        JobDefinitionVcpuReservation: !Ref JobDefinitionVcpuReservation
        JobDefinitionMemoryReservation: !Ref JobDefinitionMemoryReservation
        SesIdentityArn: !Ref SesIdentityArn
        SesFromAddress: !Ref SesFromAddress
        BaseURLForUat: !Ref BaseURLForUat
        EnvName: !Ref EnvName
        MyECSTaskExecutionRole: !Ref MyECSTaskExecutionRole
        MyECSTaskRole: !Ref MyECSTaskRole
        AppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources

Outputs:
  MyECSTaskExecutionRole:
    Value: !GetAtt ECSTaskExecutionRole.Arn
  MyECSTaskRole:
    Value: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
  MySecrets:
    Value: !Ref MyLittleSecretA
  MyECSLogGroup:
    Value: !Ref ECSLogGroup
```

In my ecs_job_definitions.yaml I have this:

```
Resources:
  AWSBatchJobDefinitionForDashboardApi:
  Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
  Properties:
    JobDefinitionName:
      !Sub
      - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-jd-dashboard"
      - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
        TheEnvName: !Ref EnvName
    PlatformCapabilities:
      - FARGATE
    PropagateTags: true
    RetryStrategy:
      Attempts: 1
    Type: container
    ContainerProperties:
      Environment:
       - Name: SES_IDENTITY_ARN
         Value: !Ref SesIdentityArn
       - Name: SES_FROM_ADDRESS
         Value: !Ref SesFromAddress
       - Name: SES_TO_ADDRESS
         Value: !Ref SesToAddress
       - Name: BASE_URL_FOR_UAT
         Value: !Ref BaseURLForUat
       - Name: CITCO_ENV
         Value: !Ref EnvName
     ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref MyCollateralECSTaskExecutionRole
     FargatePlatformConfiguration:
       PlatformVersion: LATEST
     Image: !Ref DockerImageURIForDashboard
     JobRoleArn: !Ref MyECSTaskRole
     LogConfiguration:
       LogDriver: awslogs
     NetworkConfiguration:
       AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
     ResourceRequirements:
       - Type: MEMORY
         Value: !Ref JobDefinitionMemoryReservation
       - Type: VCPU
         Value: !Ref JobDefinitionVcpuReservation
```

There are many AWS::Batch::JobDefinition so I want to isolate them under "ecs_job_definitions.yaml" and refer this from template.yaml

When doing so I also need the corresponding roles for ecs job definitions to be attached in AWS::Batch::JobDefinition, so I've the Output section in template.yaml file.

But I don't know how to refer this in my "ecs_job_definitions.yaml" file.
Any help is much appreciated.

I don't intent to Export these values, just refer them in my nested stack.

Comment: You can't. Nested stack do not see resources from parents.